# Is it bad practice to use reflection to determine method to call? Is there a better way?

Tags: java, reflection

I am currently working on a very complex program that has multiple different components, and is deployed on Client site at different stages. Release management is in place, but is a bit fiddly, and I need to change a fairly fundamental component that will impact all other libraries that will be built with it.

My question is, rather than announce it as a breaking change, and forcing all libraries to update to the new component for the next release, I'm thinking I could use reflection to see if the new class I am adding exists, if so use it, otherwise carry on using the old method. Then in a couple months' time, I will go through and remove this, and remove the old method. This means that the various client teams that are at different stages of deployment won't suddenly find they have to upgrade everything at the same time, or nothing at all.

Does this seem like it would have any obvious drawbacks, is it considered terrible practice to use reflection to 'detect version', or does this sound ok?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this feels a bit hackish, but there seems to be no other option in the situation you describe. However, you could also try to programmatically compare version numbers explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking supporting multiple versions in production adds complexity.  Hiding upgrades through things like reflection does not allow proper communication to the customers that a change has occurred.  You can and should make the upgrade as obvious to the customers as possible.  If you are rolling your changes out slowly this is fine but it does not free you from the responsibility of communication.  Detecting and using new features using reflection is not the worst practice.  I don't think you should be overly concerned about using it.